# Mac OS X doesn't show Linux Boot Partition

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ubuntu, mac

I have successfully triple-booted by mid-2012 MacBook Pro using rEFInd (a fork of rEFIt). I have Mac OS X 10.8.5, Windows 8, and Ubuntu (formatted as ext3) installed, as well as NTFS-3G for read/write between Mac and Windows. However, Mac OS X (and Windows for that matter) don't show Ubuntu as a hard drive partition. Any thoughts? I know this has been asked a million times before on the internet, but unfortunately Google couldn't save me this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu partition won't show up in the Finder (or in Explorer, in the case of Windows 8) because neither OS X nor Windows include drivers for [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3).

Take a look at this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16259/mounting-an-ext3-4-linux-external-hard-drive-to-os-x for more information on drivers for OS X and here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/ for a Windows driver.